# Webparts compatible with "Provide Data to" webpart connection

Tags: sharepoint, moss, web-parts

I am using the out of the box list viewer webpart to display a list and provide data to other webparts. I see that in the webpart connections menu, there is an option called "Provide Data to" which is always grayed out. Are there any out-of-the-box webparts that are compatible with this kind of connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS says that "Web Parts that support Web Part connections include the List View Web Part, Form Web Part, and Image Web Part.":

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointserver/HA100241051033.aspx

So, I added the forms part to my test env, as list and image were already there. Sure enough, none of them "Provide data to". The PivotView part from MOSS 2k3 did have that option, but it was removed in 2k7. Joel Oleson has a good overview:

http://blogs.msdn.com/joelo/archive/2007/01/05/what-happened-to-the-office-web-components.aspx